# Trouble Connecting Appium to Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, appium

I'm having some difficulty connecting Appium to Selenium Grid.

Here's what I have for my nodeconfig file:

```
{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName":“iPhone5”,
          "version”:”6.1,
          "maxInstances": 1,
          "platform”:”MAC”
        }
      ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "cleanUpCycle":2000,
    "timeout":30000,
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "url":`"http://127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub",`
    "host": 127.0.0.1,
    "port": 4723,
    "maxSession": 1,
    "register": true,
    "hub": `“http://192.168.28.74:4444/grid/register”`
  }
}
```

Using the Appium app, I click on launch. It doesn't throw any errors but I do not see it on the Grid console page.

If anyone has any experience connecting Appium on a Mac to the Grid, can you walk me through it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running Appium for iOS on a Mac OS X with Selenium Grid. I've tried using both with running [Selenium Server](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar) as a hub and also as running it in Jenkins via [Selenium Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin). Also as a node I run it node.js version and Appium.app version and don't have any issues.

It'll be good if you can provide some more details how exactly you are trying to run it.

Also, I've see that your nodeconfig file is looking somehow strange:

```
"browserName":“iPhone5”, <- here you have different types of double quotes " and “
"version”:”6.1 <- here the same and also one is missing.
```

So looking like you just have not a valid JSON file.

Here is example of my configuration file, which is working for me:

```
{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "iPhone5",
          "version":"7.1",
          "maxInstances": 1,
          "platform":"MAC"
        }
      ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "cleanUpCycle":2000,
    "timeout":30000,
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "url":"http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 4723,
    "maxSession": 1,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4444,
    "hubHost": "192.168.33.101"
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That did help thank you. There was an issue with parentheses. Appium is very picky about them.

Comment: I can connect to the grid, but I cannot run a test. What do you use for your driver config? Here's mine:                                 'case "iPhone":

                DesiredCapabilities iOS = DesiredCapabilities.iphone();
                iOS.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
                driver = new RemoteWebDriver (new
                        URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), iOS);

                break;'